Ubuntu 24.04.01 - broken custom hotkeys for URLs
during recent upgrade from Kubuntu 24.04 to 24.04.1 all custom shortcuts that lead to URLs seem to be broken: when I press a hotkey, I receive an error window "Launching Google (Failed). Couldn't find the program 'https://www.google.com'".
In ~/.config/khotkeysrc it looks like
Comment=Comment
Enabled=true
Name=Google
Type=SIMPLE_ACTION_DATA

[Data_5Actions]
ActionsCount=1

[Data_5Actions0]
CommandURL=https://www.google.com
Type=COMMAND_URL

[Data_5Conditions]
Comment=
ConditionsCount=0

[Data_5Triggers]
Comment=Simple_action
TriggersCount=1

[Data_5Triggers0]
Key=Ctrl+Shift+G
Type=SHORTCUT
Uuid={be6e5fdd-3b69-4af5-a52f-4ff984b6f664}

Previously under 24.04 everything worked fine. How can I return those hotkeys back?
